# dynamically align layout_gravity right &top (or top&left)

Tags: android, layout-gravity

I am a new programmer. I am trying to write a code that will dynamically change the layout gravity to top and right (or right and top) 
I did not understand how to change it to tight or left dynamically.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                    params.weight = 1.0f;
                    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
                    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                    numberhints.setLayoutParams(params);
```

the xml code that I would like to change dynamically is:

```
android:layout_gravity="top|left"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I believe would work and equivalent to your xml example :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                params.weight = 1.0f;
                params.gravity = Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT;
                numberhints.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: thanks. for some reason that's only working with Gravity.RIGHET when I change it to LEFT my apps is crushing